# Angular - http.get returning undefined

Tags: angularjs

I've created a Factory to retrieve customers:

```
customerModule.factory("CustomerFactory", ["$http", "DataService", function ($http, dataService) {

    var self = this;
    self.page = 1;
    self.query = "";

    var queryFn = function (query) {
        self.query = query;
        $http.get(dataService.baseURI + "/customers", {
            params: {
                query: self.query,
                page: self.page,
                pageSize: 50
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            return data.result;
        });
    };

    return {
        query: queryFn
    };
}]);
```

But when I use it in my controller, it returns `undefined`, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$scope.$watch("query", function () {
    if ($scope.query && $scope.query.length > 3) {
        console.log(customerFactory.query($scope.query));
    }
    else if ($scope.query.length < 4) {
        $scope.customers = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: `queryFn` returns nothing, and JS keyword for "nothing" is `undefined`.

Comment: But I thought `return data.result` would be returned? Or at least, that is what I want to be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a close look at your `queryFn` function you will notice that you're not actually **returning** anything from it. This means that `queryFn` will return `undefined`.

So the first step to fixing your code is to put `return` in front of `$http`.

Second step is fixing the way you are calling `customerFactory.query` function. You expect it to return the value immediately, but $http actually creates an XHR request, and XHR requests are async by default, so you cannot expect `customerFactory.query` to return the result right away.

If you haven't learned of **promises** than this is the time to take a look at them, because they are used all over the place, in angular world.

Assuming that you have put `return` in front of $http, the call to `customerFactory.query` will actually return a promise object. That promise object has a `.then` method. This method should be used as:

```js
customerFactory.query($scope.query)
  .then(function(customers){
    console.log(customers);
  });
```