# AngularJS - Reading JSON from Factory, using result

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

new to Angular and stuck on something that should be pretty easy...

I have a few resources:

```
.factory( 'RSVPRes', function ( $resource )  {
  return {
    RSVP: $resource("../reservations/:id.json", {id:'@id'}, {'update': {method:'PUT'}, 'remove': {method: 'DELETE', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}}),
    Meals: $resource('../meals.json'),
    UserInvites: $resource('../userinvite.json')
  };
})
```

Meals.json:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Chicken","description":"Chicken Yum!","created_at":"2013-12-11T22:37:28.994Z","updated_at":"2013-12-11T22:37:28.994Z","event_id":1,"event":{"name":"Wedding"}},{"id":2,"name":"Steak","description":"9oz","created_at":"2013-12-11T22:37:29.004Z","updated_at":"2013-12-11T22:37:29.004Z","event_id":2,"event":{"name":"Rehersal"}},{"id":3,"name":"Veggie","description":"Vegan","created_at":"2013-12-11T22:37:29.008Z","updated_at":"2013-12-11T22:37:29.008Z","event_id":3,"event":{"name":"Stag"}}]
```

UserInvites.json:

```
[{"id":18,"created_at":"2013-12-11T23:00:18.684Z","updated_at":"2013-12-11T23:00:18.684Z","event_id":1,"registry_id":1,"user_id":9,"total_in_party":2}]
```

Data seems to be formatted the same. All good here.

*EDITED* Now in my controller

```
.controller('RSVPCtrl', function RSVPController($scope, RSVPRes, $state, $stateParams) {

  //GET INVITATION(S)
  RSVPRes.UserInvites.query().$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.invitation = response.data;
    //BUILD SELECT LIST FOR MEALS
    $scope.meals = RSVPRes.Meals.query();

    //EDIT
    if ($scope.rsvpId) {
      $scope.rsvp = RSVPRes.RSVP.get({id: $scope.rsvpId}, function() {
        // $scope.selectedUser = $scope.invite.user_id;
        // $scope.selectedEvent = $scope.invite.event_id;
        // $scope.selectedRegistry = $scope.invite.registry_id;
        // $scope.selectedTotalInParty =  $scope.invite.total_in_party;
      });
    }
    //NEW 
    else {
      //INITIALIZE EMPTY GUESTS
      $scope.guests = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.invitation.total_in_party; i++) {
        $scope.guests[i] = {
          first_name: '',
          last_name: '',
          meal: 1,
          rsvp: 0
        };
      }
    }
  });

  $scope.submit = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.guests.length; i++){
       $scope.rsvp = new RSVPRes.RSVP();
       $scope.rsvp.first_name = $scope.guests[i].first_name;
       $scope.rsvp.last_name = $scope.guests[i].last_name;
       $scope.rsvp.meal_id = $scope.guests[i].meal;
       $scope.rsvp.rsvp = $scope.guests[i].rsvp;
       $scope.rsvp.$save();
    }
    $state.transitionTo('rsvps');
  };
})
```

Inspecting my response.data I get my information, however my $scope.invitation is still undefined...

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular - http.get returning undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306717/angular-http-get-returning-undefined)

Comment: @Stewie i have updated my question to reflect changes, still having some trouble understanding though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `reponse` in the callback for a `$resource` with the `response` for an `$http` GET call. You should use only `response` in the callback for the resource instead of `resource.data`. Like this:

```
  //GET INVITATION(S)
  RSVPRes.UserInvites.query().$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.invitation = response;
    //BUILD SELECT LIST FOR MEALS
    $scope.meals = RSVPRes.Meals.query();

    //EDIT
    if ($scope.rsvpId) {
      /* $scope.rsvp = RSVPRes.RSVP.get({id: $scope.rsvpId}, function() {
        // $scope.selectedUser = $scope.invite.user_id;
        // $scope.selectedEvent = $scope.invite.event_id;
        // $scope.selectedRegistry = $scope.invite.registry_id;
        // $scope.selectedTotalInParty =  $scope.invite.total_in_party;
      });*/ 
    }
    //NEW 
    else {
      //INITIALIZE EMPTY GUESTS
      $scope.guests = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.invitation.total_in_party; i++) {
        $scope.guests[i] = {
          first_name: '',
          last_name: '',
          meal: 1,
          rsvp: 0
        };
      }
    }
  });
```

From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> $promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created
>   this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or
>   collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy
>   to use in resolve section of $routeProvider.when() to defer view
>   rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
> On failure, the promise is resolved with the http response object,
>   without the resource property.

Hence, in case of *success*, the response of a `resource` is different from a `$http` call.

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/k7rMLJmQpbwWJMcfqcvl?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your **response.data** will be an array, which means that [$scope.invitation] is better named [$scope.invitations], as you're set up to get (possibly) more than one.  And that multiple invitations possibility suggests that the For loop you set up to build empty guest objects is not quite right.  Maybe try this...

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.invitation.length; i++){
    $scope.guests[i] = [];
    for (var j=0; j < $scope.guests[i].total_in_party; j++) {
        $scope.guests[i].total_in_party[j] = {
            first_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            meal: 1,
            rsvp: 0
        };
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes your are correct! Eventually I will allow a invitee to RSVP to multiple invitations, but for now I am just trying to get it to work in the basic (single invitation) case!

Comment: The point is, with the response.data you've got, $scope.invitation.total_in_party doesn't exist, but scope.invitation[0].total_in_party does exist.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing (for the time being) I have to organize some more data before I handle multiple invitations. Between you and musically_ut I solved my problem (for now) :)