# Angular resources, array in json doc not defined

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm very new to angular, and I'm not understanding why the resource is not working as expected.  When I was using the $http.get() request, I could assign it to a variable 'data', and use data.key to get the value.  This doesnt seem to work with my current resource setup, I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined", this wasn't an issue before.

```
myAppServices.factory('Apprentice',['$resource', function($resource){
  return $resource('javascripts/:apprenticeId/.json', {} ,{
    query: { method:'GET', params : {apprenticeId : 'apprentices'}, isArray:true}
  });
}]);
```

and the controller....

```
myAppControllers.controller('apprenticeCtrl',['$scope', 'Apprentice',
    function($scope, Apprentice) {

        var data = Apprentice.query();
        $scope.mainImageUrl = data.images[0];
        var index = data.images.indexOf($scope.mainImageUrl);

        $scope.setImage = function() {
          (index == data.images.length - 1) ? index= 0 : index++;

          $scope.mainImageUrl = data.images[index];
      };
  }]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular - http.get returning undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306717/angular-http-get-returning-undefined)

Comment: Not sure it is the same.  Console tells me I have no 'then' method

Comment: yeah, wouldn't it be different since his factory is created using $http and mine uses $resource?

Comment: @NoobException You're right; this is not a duplicate question.  I believe resource accepts a function that is executed when the request is complete like in my answer.

Comment: You're right about correct use, the way I had it before, the bindings weren't evaluating, but it bought that might've had something to do with the undefined.  With your solution, the bindings from other controllers evaluate, but still no defined array here.

Answer (score 0):

```
myAppControllers.controller('apprenticeCtrl',['$scope', 'Apprentice',
  function($scope, Apprentice) {

    var index;
    var data = Apprentice.query(function () {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = data.images[0];
      index = data.images.indexOf($scope.mainImageUrl);
    });

    $scope.setImage = function() {
      (index == data.images.length - 1) ? index= 0 : index++;

      $scope.mainImageUrl = data.images[index];
    };
}]);
```

I've never used `$resource` before but according to the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) you use it like that.